# A public constructor that instantiate the name array with the size parameter

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I got an error saying that cannot convert from String to int at line 5. The question requires me to instantiate the name array with the size parameter. How do I correct it?

```
class ProgClass{
private String name[];

public ProgClass(int size){
   this.name = new int[size];
}
```

then, i wanted to search the index by asking user input:

```
int cnt = cnt.nextInt
System.out.println("Name "+cnt+" is " + name[cnt-1]);
```

is there any way I can do it?

Comment: `new String[size]`

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: You are doing `String[] name = new int[size]`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: A simple *typo*? Should be `this.name = new String[size];` (notice `String` instead of `int`)

Answer (score 2):

The message should be clear: an array of strings is not an array of int.

```
this.name = new String[size];
```

is what you need. You need an "int" parameter as you want to pass the *size* to `new String[]`, but still your goal is to create an array for Strings, not for ints!

For the second part, your real problem shows up: you are inventing things.
`int cnt = cnt.nextInt` doesn't make any sense.

I guess you meant something like:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer followed by <enter>: ");
int i = reader.readInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared it as a String array but then assigned it to a new int array.

```
this.name = new String[size];
```

This just looks like a typo to me. But the issue comes from the fact that the size parameter is the integer size you want the String array to be. But it has been coded as, make my String array now be equal to a new int array which has the size I passed into the method. Which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to instantiate the String array? On line 5 you are trying to assign this.name as an array of ints of size "size".

If you change that line to

this.name = new String[size];

That would work. The individual entries would still be null though.